# How to change the colors of gameobjects in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script called `Scanner` attached to a `gameobject` also called `Scanner`. The scanner object has a child object (GFX) which has 2 Materials, the first material is called (Static Colors) and the second material is Called (Change Colors).

Scanner script:

```
public ColorNameScript.ColorName scanColor;
public Material staticMat;
public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;

private void OnValidate()
{
    if (meshRenderer != null && staticMat != null)
    {
        MaterialPropertyBlock block = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        block.SetColor("_Color", ColorNameScript.HueColourValue(scanColor));

        meshRenderer.materials[1].color = block.GetColor("_Color");
        Debug.Log("Color has changed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Missing files!");
    }
}
```

The `ColorNameScript` is just a simple script that I found online which helps me set a color through enums.

```
public enum ColorName
{
    Lime,
    Green,
    Aqua,
    Blue,
    Navy,
    Purple,
    Pink,
    Red,
    Orange,
    Yellow
}

private static Hashtable hueColourValues = new Hashtable{
     { ColorName.Lime,     new Color32( 166 , 254 , 0, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Green,     new Color32( 0 , 254 , 111, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Aqua,     new Color32( 0 , 201 , 254, 255) },
     { ColorName.Blue,     new Color32( 0 , 122 , 254, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Navy,     new Color32( 60 , 0 , 254, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Purple, new Color32( 143 , 0 , 254, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Pink,     new Color32( 232 , 0 , 254, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Red,     new Color32( 254 , 9 , 0, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Orange, new Color32( 254 , 161 , 0, 255 ) },
     { ColorName.Yellow, new Color32( 254 , 224 , 0, 255 ) },
};

public static Color32 HueColourValue(ColorName color)
{
    return (Color32)hueColourValues[color];
}
```

My Problem is: Using the scanner script as it is above is causing material leak errors in the editor (Please see picture links below), and the only way to fix it is by using `meshRenderer.sharedMaterial`, and that will work just fine, but this will change the colors of all the other scanners to the same color and I want to be able to pick different colors for each scanner. How can I do that?.

[image: Material leak error Picture]

[image: GFX materials Picture]

Comment: In the editor environment, you need clone the material, change its color, and assign it to the renderer.

Comment: @shingo i tried it but it didn't work => var newMat = new Material(staticMaterial);

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in case someone has the same problem..

```
public ColorNameScript.ColorName scanColor;
public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;

private Material[] scannerMaterials = new Material[2];

private void OnValidate()
{
    if (meshRenderer != null)
    {
        scannerMaterials[0] = Resources.Load<Material>("Static Color");
        scannerMaterials[1] = Resources.Load<Material>("Change Color");

        var tempMat = new Material(scannerMaterials[1]);
        tempMat.color = ColorNameScript.HueColourValue(scanColor);

        scannerMaterials[1] = tempMat;

        meshRenderer.sharedMaterials = scannerMaterials;
        Debug.Log("Color has changed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Missing files!");
    }
}
```

There were 2 issues:

- You can't use `meshRenderer.materials` in `OnValidate()` because it
  will cause material leak in the editor.
- Instead you have to use `meshRenderer.sharedMaterials` but this will
  set the same colors for all objects the use the same script
  `Scanner`.

**The solution is:
You have to create an array of materials and set `meshRenderer.sharedMaterials` to it.**